# Cannot view "Configure SSO" option on Github next to SSH Key

Tags: github, ssh, single-sign-on, ssh-keys

I'm ideally supposed to be seeing the "Configure SSO" option next to my SSH key but I don't. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCfBS.png)

Am I supposed to configure something elsewhere to be able to see this option?

Comment: That's only if you're running [Github Enterprise](https://github.com/enterprise).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.